# How To Remove Spaces Between Divs

Tags: css, html

I have several divs on a page and want the divs to fit together like a puzzle but when one of the divs is longer than the others the second row of the div starts at the bottom of the heightest div on the 1st row instead of moving up and covering in spaces. I have tried vertical-align and everything else related to it and still not the results i want

Comment: Replace `<div id="`...wait...what am I working with here?

Answer (score 2):

try this css code for your div -

div{ float:left}

Answer (score 1):

you can use `float` or `display: inline-block` on your `div`'s

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to position all the div the way you want. Or, relative positioning with negative values for `top` attribute. If you're using a table, do not use multiple rows. The height of a row is the maximum height of the individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you're willing to use jQuery, jQuery Masonry is a great library that does precisely what you want: http://masonry.desandro.com/